# Check if user-supplied URL will redirect to https or http

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a textbox in which the user enters url.

For example, the user enters www.google.com or http://www.google.com. But google redirects all http requests to https.

How can I check whether the server which serves an url will enforce http or https from the string which the user enters?

I.e. if the user entered http://www.google.com, I need to return https.

Comment: Try with `indexOf` or a regex.

Comment: Short answer - you can't.  You can only see what they've entered, not tell how it will be resolved by a remote server.

Comment: Do you just want to check if the user input starts with `http:` or `https` or do you actually need to know if the webserver the URL points to redirects HTTP request to HTTPS requests?

Comment: @Philipp I want to know if the webserver the URL points to redirects HTTP request to HTTPS requests.

Comment: Google on http is perfectly valid. It just so happens they have https available too.

Comment: @gvee I know that is valid. I never said otherwise. It just gets redirected to https. I need to get that info.

Comment: @petko_stankoski I really don't think you can. I'd love to be proved wrong though!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from Javascript.

The only way to obtain this information is by actually requesting the URL and checking the HTTP response header the server responds with. When the status code is 301 (moved permanently) or 307 (moved temporarily) and the URL in the `Location:`-header of the response uses a different protocol, it seems to be a redirect from http to https or vice-versa. But unfortunately there is no API to do this and obtain this information with client-sided Javascript.

As a workaround you could send the URL to your server and use server-sided programming to request the website and check the status-code. But note that the response the target-server will give your server is not necessarily the same it would give to the client, because rewrite-rules can be complex.

Answer (score -2):

Use JavaScript `match` function.

```
$("#inputField").val().match(/^http/);
```

Or in a if statement

```
if (null !== $("#inputField").val().match(/^http/)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you need more flexibility just bind some events on the input field. Then you can check this on the fly.

Comment: The problem is this: The user enters www.google.com. See now?

Comment: And btw downvoting the question because I don't accept your answer is pretty unfair.

Comment: And the match will fail. So you can return what ever you want. Come on its simple if-else. I told how you can check. You can combine this with an OR... If you expect more, then modify your question, post some code so we can see the problem...

Comment: Dear God you don't seem to get it. The user enters www.google.com. I need to return https. How can I do that?? THAT is the question.

Comment: Down rating a correct answer is fair? What ever I told you the solution accept it, clarify your problem, or do it on your own way!

Comment: This is the same way: if ("www.google.com".match(/^www\.google\.com/)) { return "https"; } Try it in a console. This will work and answers your question.

Comment: Ok that works for google. Do I need to add a check for every website on the internet?

Comment: @createproblem Your answer is not correct because you misunderstood the question. I clarified it based on the comments of the author.

Comment: Yeah OK I didn't noticed the question changes... I don't know how can I see that, when something is changed... quickly in a short time. Its right my answer is wrong! I'm sorry!